getting the current user in Tridion integration framework connector
Does anyone have any idea how to get the current used in the Tridion integration framework connector?
I see IUser interface, but how do I get it in the code?

I guess "the current used" should be "the current user" ?

Most Connector methods have an (optional) parameter of type IConnectorContext, which is defined as:
public interface IConnectorContext : IValueObject
{
    string CorrelationId { get; }
    IUser User { get; }
    bool InTrustedMode { get; }
    string EnvironmentId { get; }
    string EnvironmentType { get; }
    string Language { get; }
    IDictionary<string, string> Properties { get; }
}  

Whether the parameter is specified or not depends on the host, but ECL will specify it.  The IConnectorContext.User will reflect the CM User.
Note the difference between IConnectorContext.User.Language and IConnectorContext.Language. The former is probably obvious, the latter reflects the context Publication Language/Locale (if set).
